# C# using statement

Tags: c#, using, using-statement

I really want to get this out of my head. Please see below code:

```
using (DataTable resultTable = DBUtility.GetSingleDBTableResult(connectionString, "SELECT * FROM MyDBTable")) {
    List<string> resultsList = new List<string>();
    foreach (DataRow dataRow in resultTable.Rows) {
        resultsList.Add(dataRow[0].ToString());
    }
    return resultsList;
}
```

Is the datatable disposed? Can someone explain how this is translated to a try/catch/finally block? MSDN states that if an exception occurred, the Dispose method will still be called but what about the return statement?

Or should i just use below code:

```
List<string> resultsList = new List<string>();
using (DataTable resultTable = DBUtility.GetSingleDBTableResult(connectionString, "SELECT * FROM MyDBTable")) {
    foreach (DataRow dataRow in resultTable.Rows) {
        resultsList.Add(dataRow[0].ToString());
    }
}
return resultsList;
```

Probably, the second one should be used but I just need enlightenment :). Please explain. Thanks.

Comment: Put your return wherever you want, the Dispose will be called regardless. 'Using' is your friend!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`using` statement is just syntactic sugar and it gets translated into try/finally block. Starting with your code, here's how the C# compiler will translate the `using` block into try/finally block.

```
        try
        {
            DataTable resultTable = DBUtility.GetSingleDBTableResult(connectionString, "SELECT * FROM MyDBTable");
            List<string> resultsList = new List<string>();
            foreach (DataRow dataRow in resultTable.Rows)
            {
                resultsList.Add(dataRow[0].ToString());
            }
            return resultsList; 
        }
        finally
        {
            resultTable.Dispose();
        }
```

As you can see from the code, the resultTable gets disposed for sure regardless of the return statement. The using block only makes sure that object gets disposed after the scope.

Your first code looks ok to me and need not be changed.

Answer (score 4):

`Using` **does not** catch exceptions, it just guarantees the `.Dispose()` call.

This is because,

`using (ResourceType resource = new ResourceType())` is equivalent to:

```
ResourceType resource;
try 
{
     resource = new ResourceType();
     /* The insides of the using block */
}
finally
{
    resource.Dispose();
}
```

The `.Dispose()` call will *always* be evaluated.  The `Dispose` call is even evaluated if you return within your `using` block (before it "really" returns). The `Dispose` call is even evaluated if an exception is thrown.

However, if an exception is thrown, that exception will still prevent subsequent lines of code from being evaluated (with the exception of the `.Dispose()` which is *always* evaluated).

As such, if an exception occurs, your `return` will not return in either of your statements, but your `DataTable` will still be disposed.

If you want to guarantee a return occurs, even when an error occurs, you want to do something like this:

```
List resultsList = new List();
try
{
    using (DataTable resultTable = DBUtility.GetSingleDBTableResult(connectionString, "SELECT * FROM MyDBTable")) 
    {
        foreach (DataRow dataRow in resultTable.Rows) 
        {
            resultsList.Add(dataRow[0].ToString());
        }
    }
}
catch
{
}
return resultsList;
```

Answer (score 1):

The DataTable is disposed (`.Dispose` is called) in both cases.

It's translated into a `try/finally`, with `Dispose` being called in the `finally`. Finally, as the name implies, is called even when you call `return`.

Answer (score 1):

In both your examples, `Dispose` will be called.  This is because the using statement expands to a try/finally block.

Go read the [C# Language Specification](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=dfbf523c-f98c-4804-afbd-459e846b268e) (8.13 The using statement) to find out the various scenarios (for reference types, non-nullable value types, and dynamic types).

Since `DataTable` is a reference type, your first sample will expand to the following:

```
{
    DataTable resultTable = DBUtility.GetSingleDBTableResult(connectionString, "SELECT * FROM MyDBTable");
    try {
        List<string> resultsList = new List<string>();
        foreach (DataRow dataRow in resultTable.Rows) {
           resultsList.Add(dataRow[0].ToString());
        }
        return resultsList;
    }
    finally {
        if (resultTable != null) ((IDisposable)resultTable).Dispose();
    }
}
```