# Using using in a constructor

Tags: c#, stream, using

I am using a create method for a constructor of a converter.

```
public void loadData()
{
    byte [] data = new byte [] {......}; // some byte data in here
    var converter = GetDataConverter(data);
}
```

Now inside the GetDataConverter I need to create a memorystream from the binary data (the converter is 3rd party and takes a stream)
If I write the GetDataConverter like this I get an error telling me I didnt' dispose which I understand. I created a MemoryStream and I need to dispose.

```
public MyDataConverter GetDataConverter(byte [] data)
{
    return new MyDataConverter(new MemoryStream(data));
}
```

So my solution would be this:

```
public MyDataConverter GetDataConverter(byte [] data)
{
    using(var ms = new MemoryStream(data))
    {
       return new MyDataConverter(ms);
    }
}
```

The question is, is my solution correct? Should I be using a 'using' here? isn't the 'using' going to destroy my memory stream once it's out of scope so the converter will have nothing to work on?

I need an answer AND an explanation please, I'm a bit vague on the whole 'using' thing here.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# using statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183458/c-sharp-using-statement)

Comment: ´MyDataConverter´ should implement ´IDisposable´ and take care of disposing the ´MemoryStream´.

Comment: @vape: That one doesn't really answer my question. I want to know how will the 'using' affect the rest of my converter if I call it around the constructor.

Comment: @user3177615 use solution which Alessandro suggests (actually I think it worth being posted as answer)

Comment: MemoryStream will be disposed before return execution

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria I don't have access to the dataconverter and anyway it takes a stream as an input, why would it be responsible for cleaning up that stream?

Comment: @user3177615 because it uses disposable resource. When resource is not needed anymore, it is responsibility of resource user to clean up that resource. Rule of thumb is following - if your class uses IDisposable resource, then class should be IDisposable also

Comment: @user3177615 Sergey comment is correct ´MemoryStream´ is owned by ´MyDataConverter´, this make the type responsible for disposing the resources it uses.

Comment: hmm .. well like I said I don't have access to the converter class. I'll therefore have to do come clean-ups in my own code. I was hoping just clearing up the memorystream with the using would do the job. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have no access to the code of ´MyDataConverter´ and the type doesn't implements ´IDisposable´ you can do:

```
public void loadData()
{
    byte[] data = new byte[] { 0 }; // some byte data in here

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(data))
    {
        var converter = new MyDataConverter(stream);

        // do work here...
    }
}
```

If you have to use this many times and want to reuse your code you can do something like this:

```
public void loadData()
{
    byte[] data = new byte[] { 0 }; // some byte data in here

    UsingConverter(data, x =>
    {
        // do work here...
    });
}

void UsingConverter(byte[] data, Action<MyDataConverter> action)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(data))
    {
        var converter = new MyDataConverter(stream);

        action(converter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the implementation of `MyDataConverter`. If the `MemoryStream` is only used inside the constructor to retrieve some data from it, then your solution with `using` is OK.
If, OTOH, `MyDataConverter` keeps a reference to the MemoryStream to access it later, you must not dispose it here.